# Physics-based Walking (from A New Zero)

Tags: physics, game-physics, physics-engine, bulletphysics

I saw this video and I was amazed, and naturally, I want to try to do it myself. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_DeZUg9HiY

Does anyone have any idea how he made the character walk? Look at the video at 1:15. What kind of Bullet physics constraints do you think he's using in the legs? Is he making some kind of springs?

Comment: Have you tried asking him about it?  http://www.crypticsea.com/ has contact info.

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge area of academic research. See this paper for starters:

http://graphics.stanford.edu/projects/bio-locomotion/

A game could definitely use a much simpler control scheme than that used in the paper.

Comment: Awesome link. Very inspirational stuff. Way over my head, of course.

Comment: What's your background? SIMBICON is a simpler walking controller https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~van/papers/Simbicon.htm. They have source code for their controller on that website. In the next few days, I hope to put online a version of their controller as part of the Simbody multibody dynamics library (github.com/simbody/simbody.git).

Comment: Hahahaha my background is high school.